# compare each item in two different list in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am having two List of items,

```
public class DataExcel
{
    public String Name{ get; set; }
    public String Color { get; set; }
    public String Comments { get; set; }
    public String Management { get; set; }
}

// before inserting data into DB i am fetching all the values into a List

//This method will get all the details from Db
List<DataExcel> dBUpdate = GetAllExistingDrugList();

//some logic to insert data into DB                 
//After inserting the data again i am fetching all the values into another List

List<DataExcel dBUpdate1  = GetAllExistingDrugList();
```

Now i want to compare `dBUpdate` with `dBUpdate1`, if the drugs are having same name but the other details have been modified then i should display the count of drugs which have been modified and inserted.

Example in first insertion i am inserting

1.Name:"A"
Color :"Red"
Comments :"1st insertion"
Management :"slow"

2.Name:"B"
Color :"Green"
Comments :"2st insertion"
Management :"slow"

*2nd insertion*

1.Name:"A"
Color :"Green"
Comments :"1st insertion"
Management :"slow"

2.Name:"B"
Color :"Green"
Comments :"2st insertion"
Management :"slow"

So in", second insertion i have changed the color of "A" from "Red" to "Green Now i should display Update Count as 1.

Can any one please help me out

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if this is the best way. But it is the simplest and the first thing that occurred to me:

```
int UpdateCount = 0;
foreach (DataExcel item in dBUpdate)
{
    if(!dBUpdate1.Contains(item))
    {
       UpdateCount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this could work:

```
var count = (from d1 in dBUpdate join d2 in dBUpdate1 on d1.Name equals d2.Name
                where d1.Color != d2.Color || d1.Comments != d2.Comments || d1.Management != d2.Management
                select d1).Count();
```

Both list are joined but only when d1 and d2 have the same Name and when there is a different entry in Color, Comments or Management. So it is a list of all drugs that were changed which are simply counted at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

```
// counter
int updatedRecords = 0;

foreach(var dataExcel in dBUpdate)
{
    // Find the associated record for the dataExcel in the second list.
    var dataExcel1 = dBUpdate1.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Name==dataExcel.Name);

    // If the associated record found check if anything changed 
    // to it's properties values.
    if(dataExcel1!=null)
    {
        // If any change has been made, update the counter.
        if(dataExcel1.Color!= dataExcel.Color || 
           dataExcel1.Comments != dataExcel.Comments || 
           dataExcel1.Management != dataExcel.Management )
            updatedRecords++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;

dBUpdate.ForEach(dbu =>
{
       dBUpdate1.Where(dbu1 => dbu1.Name.Equals(dbu.Name)).ToList().ForEach(dbu11 =>
       {
              if (!dbu11.Color.Equals(dbu.Color) || !dbu11.Comments.Equals(dbu.Comments) || 
                        !dbu11.Management.Equals(dbu.Management))
                 {
                    count++;
                 }
        });

});

We can use linQ expressions also.
```